# How to create multi serial for one item

Tags: c#, sql

I have an inventory management system as it contains items and for each item it has its(  model - brand - exp date - serial number)  the question is how can I assign multi serial number for one item

Comment: make a secont table with a foreign key to your item in the first table. Then shove all the serial numbers there in. Did I understood you correctly?

Comment: Your question is quite vague - Add more detail like table structure and possibly source code to generate a much better response from the community. 

*PS Welcome to StackOverflow!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either :

1. Create an Item entity and an SerialNumber entity and make a 1-n relation between them (Item foreign key into SerialNumber table)
2. Or if you don't need to make requests on SerialNumber, you can add a serialized json property on Item, containing a list of your serial numbers

Comment: Thanks I will stick for option 1

Comment: @AmmarHesham Feel free to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. :)